# How to make an element with a border on hover not increase its computed height/width

Tags: html, css, dom

A common problem I encounter is that I want to make an element have a border on hover, but when the border comes in the element's computed height and width increase, making it visually jump and sometimes push elements. Is there a way to cure this without using `max-width` and `max-height`?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdzm9yfu/

```
<style>
    #mydiv { background: yellow; padding: 15px; border: 0; }
    #mydiv:hover { border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>Here's an element. Watch the text jump when the border appears.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to apply a **transparent border** by default:

```
<style>
    #mydiv {
        background: yellow; 
        padding: 15px; border: 0;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    #mydiv:hover { border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having no border when it's not being hovered, how about giving it a transparent 1px border? That way, it'll always have the same spacing, just a different color on hover.

```
<style>
    #mydiv { background: yellow; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid transparent; }
    #mydiv:hover { border-color: black; }
</style>
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>Here's an element. Watch the text jump when the border appears.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` into your CSS for `#mydiv`. That means that the padding and borders are included in the elements height and widht, not in addition to.

Or.. set your border to yellow to match the content div background colour.

Answer (score 0):

use `box-sizing:border-box` to make your width and height include your border

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

> border-box - The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin

Comment: That doesn't solve it; here's his jsfiddle with that CSS rule added: https://jsfiddle.net/xdzm9yfu/2/